# Print each items of List N times

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming

I'm new to Scala/Functional Programming and want to understand if my below solution fits into the functional programming world. If someone can suggest me a better approach, I will be obliged.

**Problem Statement:** Print each item of a list, n times

**Solution:**

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object ListReplication extends App {


  def printNTimes(items: List[Int], n: Int): ListBuffer[Int] = {

    var outputList = new ListBuffer[Int]

    def storeNTime(item: Int): Unit = {

      for (_ <- 1 to n) outputList += item

    }

    for (item <- items) storeNTime(item)

    outputList
  }

  val result = printNTimes(items = List(1,2,4), n = 3)
  println(result)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is always better to work with immutable types. So I'll change the return type into `List[Int]`. You can just do:

```scala
def printNTimes(items: List[Int], n: Int): List[Int] = {
  items.flatMap(i => Vector.fill(n)(i))
}
```

or:

```scala
def printNTimes(items: List[Int], n: Int): List[Int] = {
  items.flatMap(Vector.fill(n)(_))
}
```

Then running:

```
println(printNTimes(List(1,2,4), 3))
```

will output:

```
List(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4)
```

Comment: Wonderful use of immutable collections! TBH, for a newbie like me, it's bit difficult to think in such a direction and come up with a solution (as I have just started with functional programming).

Comment: @Sumit three advices; Forbid your self for using any kind of mutability. Check the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/). Search for some book / tutorial / course that guides you step by step into FP. - Happy coding!

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Already on it. Started reading and executing codes from "Programming in Scala" . Thanks for your valuable suggestion!