# Expand the size of a List by N

Tags: list, scala

I am having difficulty in phrasing this question so I apologies for the vague sounding title.

I started learning Scala today. I would like to generate a list of elements, and then multiply that list by a factor N, with the result as follows:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4) * N -> List(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4) (where N = 2)
```

In Python, I would just do the following which would yield what I am looking for:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4] * 2
```

However, this does not work in Scala.

Comment: perhaps something like `Range(0,2).toList.flatMap(x => List(1, 2, 3, 4))`

Comment: Similar but not exactly the same: [Print each items of List N times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65664399/2359227)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`List.fill`](https://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/collection/immutable/List$.html#fill-3a1)

```
List.fill(2)(List(1, 2, 3, 4)).flatten
// : List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

or provide extension method to mimic Python, something like

```
extension (l: List[Int]) 
  def *(n: Int): List[Int] = List.fill(n)(l).flatten

List(1, 2, 3, 4) * 2
// : List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that:

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val n = 2
val result = (1 to n)
  .flatMap(_ => l)
  .toList
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option you have is:

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val length = l.length
List.tabulate(length * n)(i => l(i % length))
```

Comment: Note that if the list is somewhat big, this approach is very inefficient due that all operations here are **O(N)**, you may want to transform that `List` into an `ArraySeq` first.

Comment: Yeap @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, you are right :)